# What is the $\mu^2$ squared effect size?

Tags: effect-size

I was recently looking at a paper in the journal *Psychological Science* and came across this:

*F*(1, 71) = 4.5, *p* = .037, $\mu^2$ = .06

*F*(1, 71) = 0.08, *p* = .78, $\mu^2$ = .001

I was wondering what the $\mu^2$ is in the above. Typically in APA the third thing should be either the MSE or it should be a standardized effect size (or you should have all 4). I'm guessing it's a standardized effect size of some sort but I'm not familiar with it and searching the net has turned up nothing. The actual effect, as near as I can tell from the graph, is about 12 for the first one.

Is this an effect size I haven't heard of yet or a typo in the article?

Farrelly, D., Slater, R., Elliott, H. R., Walden, H. R. and Wetherell, M. A. (2013) Competitors Who Choose to Be Red Have Higher Testosterone Levels. *Psychological Science*, DOI:10.1177/0956797613482945

Here's a screen shot of the text (p.2)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of this referring to $\eta^2$, computed as:

$\eta^2={SS_{effect} \over SS_{total}}$

This is the proportion of variance explained in the dependent variable by the grouping variable (in this case, a binary variable). This would be indeed the same value as the $R^2$ obtained if the difference between the two groups was estimated using simple linear regression:

$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1group_i+\epsilon_i$

I can see from the paper that the second F test is actually that of an interaction term, and since it has 1 degree of freedom, I am deducing that the second factor was also a binary variable. In this case, the $\eta^2$'s are partial $\eta^2$'s, which are the proportion of variance explained by the grouping variable (or the interaction term) controlling for the other grouping variable. In this more complex case, the partial $\eta^2$'s are the same as the partial $R^2$'s obtained from the multiple linear regression:

$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1group_{1i}+\beta_2group_{1i}+\beta_3 \cdot group_{1i} \cdot group_{2i} + \epsilon_i$

Comment: Given that no one else has come up with an alternative I'll mark this correct. However Patrick it's entirely possible this is an (misapplied) $\omega^2$. The $\eta^2$ better suits a typo I think (upside down $\mu$?).

Answer (score 1):

This is eta-squared and it is a fairly poor measure of effect size (partial eta-squared is often reported in statistical software such as SPSS when calculating ANOVA)

Comment: If it is $\eta^2$ (and it may well be) then it is indeed a typo, since the question listed it as $\mu^2$

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I misread Patrick's response above; I now see he also indicated it was $_{partial}\eta^2$. I added the formulas for finding $_{partial}\eta^2$ should any need those.

---

I am posting on this old thread to clarify should others visit in the future. The value reported is $_{partial}\eta^2$, not $\eta^2$. Since the analysis is a two-way ANOVA, the formula $\frac{(F)(df_a)}{(F)(df_a)+df_e}$ (where $df_a$ is df for the predictor and $df_e$ is the error df) which normally provides $\eta^2$ for a one-way ANOVA, instead produces the $_{partial}\eta^2$ for a multi-way ANOVA.

Thus
$_{partial}\eta^2$ = $\frac{(F)(df_a)}{(F)(df_a)+df_e}$ = $\frac{4.5}{4.5+71}$ = .059 ~ .06

and

$_{partial}\eta^2$ = $\frac{(F)(df_a)}{(F)(df_a)+df_e}$ = $\frac{.08}{.08+71}$ = .001

The authors mislabeled the effect, rather than $\mu^2$ it should be $_{partial}\eta^2$.

It is also possible the authors meant to report Cohen's $f^2$ effect size since the results of these two F-ratios provide both $_{partial}\eta^2$ and $f^2$ that are within rounding error, but I have never seen Cohen $f^2$ reported like this.

Bryan

Comment: Nice first answer. Note that you can make your math more readable by using Latex math notation (see here for more details: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation )

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have updated the response to use the Latex option - I was not aware of that option.